# Asana typeahead endpoint returns all projects for Personal Projects workspace

Tags: asana

When using the [typeahead endpoint](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/typeaheads) to search for projects in my *Personal Projects* workspace, it returns all of my projects. The results don't change for different queries and the `count` parameter is ignored. I don't have this problem for other workspaces/organizations. Is this expected since *Personal Projects* are special or is this a bug?

Comment: (I work at Asana.) This is unexpected. We'll try to reproduce on our end and see what's going on. We have had reports in the past of strange issues related to using the API with Personal Projects. We'll answer on this task when we have something more definitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

To answer the question, yes it is a bug. But also, in general you can expect issues when dealing with Personal projects as they are indeed special.

We've addressed the filtering issue and the results you get should be filtered by query (required) and count (optional) now. Thanks for reporting!